# How do I merge duplicate cells together with google app script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I currently have a list with two columns. The first column is student name, and the second column is the number of points they have.

I imported this list from multiple spreadsheets so there were many duplicates on the names of the students. I am able to remove the duplicates, but I want to keep a tally on the total points they have. For example:

Amy   10
Bob   9
Carol 15
Amy   12

would turn into:

Amy   22
Bob   9
Carol 15

This is what I have so far:

```
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:B1000").getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  var k = 0
  var finallist = []
  for(i in data){
    k++;
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row[0] == newData[j][0]){
        duplicate = true;
        var storedHour = sheet.getRange("B"+k).getValue();
        var position = finallist.indexOf(row[0]);
        var originalCell = sheet.getRange("B"+(position+1));
        var originalHour = originalCell.getValue();
        originalCell.setValue(originalHour + storedHour);
        sheet.getRange(k,2).setValue("")
        sheet.getRange(k,1).setValue("")
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
      finallist.push(row[0])
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that we have a really large data sample and I'm afraid it may run over Google's 5 minute maximum execution time. Is there another more efficient way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Hi Qilin, what is not working as you'd expect? What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to put the actual problem in the description! How careless. I was just wondering how to make the code more efficient because I want to execute it under Google's 5 minute maximum execution time. I'll add that now to the description.

Comment: Haha, easily done, no worries. I don't know much about Google Scripts, but off-the-cuff I get the feeling something like MapReduce or splitting the task into seperate jobs might work.

Comment: I guess you're right. I could just split the task into two halves if it ever goes over the limit. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a =query() in a cell?  I WANT to say that could get what you are after if you get the select statement correct, but I have never worked with groupings in a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running slow because Spreadsheets API methods (like `getRange`) are time consuming and much slower then other JavaScript code.

Here is optimized function with reduced number of such Spreadsheets API calls:

```
function calcNumbers()
{
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, 2);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var pointsByName = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
    var row = data[i];
    var curName = row[0];
    var curNumber = row[1];

    // empty name
    if (!curName.trim())
    {
      continue;
    }

    // if name found first time, save it to object
    if (!pointsByName[curName])
    {
      pointsByName[curName] = Number(curNumber);
    }
    // if duplicate, sum numbers
    else
    {
      pointsByName[curName] += curNumber;
    }
  }

  // prepare data for output
  var outputData = Object.keys(pointsByName).map(function(name){
    return [name, pointsByName[name]];
  });

  // clear old data
  dataRange.clearContent();

  // write calculated data
  var newDataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, outputData.length, 2);
  newDataRange.setValues(outputData);
}
```

Comment: Something akin to a tally board. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting before comparing allows looking at the next item only instead of all items for each iteration. A spillover benefit is finallist result is alphabatized. Execution time reduction significant.

```
function sumDups() {
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().sort();
  var finallist = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<= data.length - 1; i++){
    var hours = data[i][1];
    while((i < data.length - 1) && (data[i][0] == data[i+1][0])) {
       hours += data[i+1][1];
       i++;
       };
    finallist.push([data[i][0], hours]);
  };
  Logger.log(finallist);
}
```

Edit: the simple data structure with the name being in the first column allows this to work. For anything more complex understanding and applying the methods shown in @Kos's answer is preferable